Firestore query with orderBy and limit in infinite scroll list
I have an infinite scroll table of items in my app. Once the table is rendered, I subscribe to first 20 items. This is the query in my listener:
const firestoreQuery = query(
collectionGroup(firestore, 'items'),
orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'),
startAfter(Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(startValue))), // startValue is now() + 1min to ensure no items are skipped
limit(20));

The idea is that I store the createdAt attribute of the last (20th) item. That way, once the user scrolls a little bit through the initial batch, I call the query again and send it different startValue.
Given orderBy statement is createdAt descending:
1st call (on page load): startValue = now() + 1min to ensure no items are skipped
2nd call (on table scroll): startValue = (20th item).createdAt
3rd call (on table scroll): startValue = (40th item).createdAt
The issue is that an item created 2 min after the 1st (page load) query will not be returned as it has effectively been skipped by the startValue. If I instead do not pass the startValue at all in the 1st (page load) call, it is possible that it will also not be returned due to limit(20) statement => the initial call might return 20 items and the newly created one would have been 21st and is therefore excluded.
How do I fix this?


The idea is that I store the createdAt attribute of the last (20th) item.

Instead of storing document field data to determine the next page, you're supposed to store the entire snapshot of the document that was last seen, and provide that snapshot to startAfter.  This is discussed in the documentation.  You won't miss any documents if you do this, assuming that any new documents that would be part of the query are ordered at the end of the query.  If you're using server timestamps for the values of the createdAt field, this won't be a problem.

Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain why would using query cursor prevent me from missing the documents, not sure why that behaves different as opposed to a date (or any other field). I don't think this is explained anywhere in the docs. Furthermore, what about the second part of the question around the limit(20) statement already being executed and all the 20 items being already "spent"?

Document snapshots offer an unambiguously specific position into the result set, regardless of the actual values in use, which Firestore can use to reliably show you the next one after it in the order.  Raw field values can never do that for you, as you have already discovered.  There is no "spent" items in Firestore queries, only position from the document you specify, since all the documents have a set ordering defined by the query you provide.

If you feel the documentation is incomplete or unclear, you can use the "send feedback" button at the top of any page to let the authors know your thoughts.

what if I just don't set startAfter() on the initial request at all? What issues can this approach lead to, as opposed to if I were using a document snapshot as a cursor?

Then you get the first page of results.
